# Why can we always color array with at most 11 colors?

Tags: algorithm, greedy, number-theory

I have been trying to solve this problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1332/problem/B

The solution: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/75432

I understand that since a_i < 1000, there are exactly 11 primes that can be its factor (since a factor f < sqrt(1000)). So we can color each a_i based on its lowest prime factor, since we have 11 colors available. But what if we were given an array, a, where the first 11 numbers are the first 11 smallest primes and the last element is a prime number, p, where p > 32. We couldn't assign it any of the 11 colors since for any colored a_i, gcd(a_i, p) = 1. So we would need a 12th color.

I don't understand why I am wrong with this argument, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Alice is given a sequence of  composite numbers", i.e., not prime.

Comment: Ohh right, well now I feel silly. Thank you